# Add content to top-right area of rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

After various attempts with pull-right, float style and row-fluid, I decided to ask here:

What I try to do is simply to have a Map appear to the right of a set of rows.

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Which is not too far from what I want, but the name row plus any following rows should appear below each other.

Here is how my HTML looks:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-10 pull-right">
            <google-map id="my-map" bounds="map.bounds" events="map.events"
                center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true"
                control="map.control"> <marker ng-if="positionMarker"
                coords="positionMarker" icon="positionMarker.icon"> </marker> </google-map>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Number</span> <input type="number"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Nr">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span> <input type="text"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I bet this is a typical scenario but I have failed to find an example.

Other attempts that makes name appear below number, moves it below the map.

Is it perhaps possible to avoid having the map take up vertical space in the Bootstrap grid system?

Comment: can you post a fiddle? I'll fix it for you there

Comment: can you also provide your `CSS`?

Comment: @Kyojimaru not using any special css, only bootstrap

Comment: @GusDB Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cyrixmorten/fwda2su8/ map has been replaced by a green box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a 2-col layout :

- Left column for your inputs
- Right column for your Google Map

Plus, remember to put your `.input-group` inside a `.form-group` to get paddings/margins set to Bootstrap default values.

Here's a working example (click on <kbd>Full page</kbd> for a better view):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; 
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel heading</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">Number</span> <input type="number"
              class="form-control" placeholder="Nr">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span> <input type="text"
              class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Da bomb! :D I just knew it had to be simple once the right take on it was found. Just cannot believe that any of my attempts did not hit this combination, hehe. Thank you, and thanks for the suggested improvements!

Comment: Can I ask you why you choose col-xs-* over, for instance, col-lg-*?

Comment: That was just for snippet purpose (they're rendered in a 660px width box).